# How does Windows keep track of application window layout, and how do I reset it?

Tags: windows, winforms

I've just pulled a piece of code from the company git repo, and when I ran it for the first time, the layout of the components were awkward. I though the software was not working properly, then realized that the source code shows the window with that initial layout. This is a windows forms application written with C#, and my development machine is Windows 7

I've manually changed the layout through moving stuff around, and killed the debugging session. Now when I start the debugging/execution again, the window appears with the layout I've configured. I did not install this program or anything, but windows remembers the layout for this window, and I can't describe or demonstrate the initial layout to other members of the team. Cleaning the solution, rebuilding etc did not help. I can delete the local repo and do everything from scratch, but this is not a solution, just an annoying walkaround.

where is this information kept, and how do I reset it?

Ps: Searching for the solution through Google is another nightmare, since I can't think of keywords other than "windows layout history " etc...

Comment: I am not sure what is the 'layout' you are talking about, but I bet that it is your application that write/persist somewhere the information needed to restore its last 'layout'

Comment: I'm not familiar with git, but in svn, there is a revert function that will restore the file or project to the last commit.

Comment: Layout is not persisted.  Surely the problem is that your video DPI setting is different from the last machine.

Comment: After talking to team who wrote the code, we found out that someone did a custom implementation deep down in the code. So Steve is right, but I can't mark his comment as an accepted answer. @Steve , care to answer so that I can accept your answer as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uncommon to write custom code to persist the layout of windows (position, size) and controls like splitpanels (or grid column size). This is usually done to present the last know layout to the end user. Windows doesn't offer a pre-built solution to this task because unintended consequences could arise (think about changing screen resolution and then restore a window to a now, out of screen position).

I am sure that it is your application that write/persist somewhere the information needed to restore its last 'layout'